The Value That Appears as a Number on the Angular Side Appears in Date Format in the Backend (.NET)
Although there is no problem in the model I sent while saving in my Angular project, the id value appears in date format on the backend side.
This problem only occurs with 4-digit values. For example, when the id value is 82321, it appears normal in the backend, but when it is a value such as 4781, it appears as 1970-01-01T02:00:04.781.
The date format appears in formDataWithFilesDto before the deserialization process.
My .ts code:
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  studentId = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.studentId = Number(this.config.data.studentId || '0');
    console.log(typeof(this.studentId)) // appears as number in console.
  }

  saveStudent() {
    const model = {
      id: this.studentId,
      // Other properties.
    }

    this.myService.saveStudent(model).subscribe(result => {
      if (result.resultType == ResultType.Success) {
        this.ch.messageHelper.showSuccessMessage(result.messages.toString());
      } else {
        this.ch.messageHelper.showErrorMessage(result.messages.toString());
      }
    });
  }
}

My backend code:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ServiceResult> SaveStudent([FromForm] FormDataWithFilesDto formDataWithFilesDto)
{
  return await _myService.SaveStudent(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SaveStudentDto>(formDataWithFilesDto.FormData), formDataWithFilesDto.UploadedFiles).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

FormDataWithFilesDto:
public class FormDataWithFilesDto
{
  public string FormData { get; set; }
  public long? RefId { get; set; }
  public List<FileUploadDto> UploadedFiles { get; set; }
  public T GetData<T>()
  {
    if (FormData != null)
    {
      return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(FormData);
    }
    return default(T);
  }
}

SaveStudentDto:
public class SaveStudentDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  // Other properties.
}

Here's what I tried:

I tried to create a model according to types on the Angular side and send it that way, but the result did not change.
I used parseInt instead of Number but the result is the same.
I sent it with String instead of number or parseInt, but it still appears as date.

Edit: When I check model with console.log, the model I sent on the frontend is as follows:
{
  id: 4781,
  studentName: 'John',
  studentSurname: 'Doe',
  examName: 'Maths',
  examGrade: 50,
  examDate: Tue May 14 2024 00:24:42 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
}

When I check the Network tab, the model I sent looks like this, so it also looks like this in the backend:
{
  "id": "1970-01-01T02:00:04.781",
  "studentName": "John",
  "studentSurname": "Doe",
  "examName": "Maths",
  "examGrade": 50,
  "examDate": "2024-05-14T00:24:42.812"
}

Apart from these, the service.ts file and the generic function used here are as follows:
Service.ts:
saveStudent(model: any) {
  return this.httpHelper.post<any>(
    this.moduleport,
    this.controllerName,
    'SaveStudent',
    this.ch.createFormDataWithFiles(['saveStudentFile'], model)
  ));
}

createFormDataWithFiles function and that's why the dto in the backend will fit the following structure:
createFormDataWithFiles(fileParameterNames: string[], additionalObject: any) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const fileObjectName = 'uploadedFiles';
  const additionalObjectName = 'formData';
  for (let i = 0; i < fileParameterNames.length; i++) {
    const fileParameterName = fileParameterNames[i];
    formData.append(`${fileObjectName}[${i}].value`, fileParameterName.toString());
    const files = this.globals.fileUploadFormData.getAll(fileParameterName);
    for (const file of files) {
      formData.append(`${fileObjectName}[${i}].files`, file);
    }
  }
  if (!this.isNullOrUndefined(additionalObject) && !this.isNullOrWhiteSpace(additionalObjectName)) {
    formData.append(additionalObjectName, JSON.stringify(additionalObject));
  }
  return formData;
}


something must be converting this to DateTime on the backend.  As is, you have a very unstructured model on the backend, so something's making assumptions about your generic type.  Why not bind to a structured model on the backend?  Right now you're doing some odd parsing/deserializing when .NET will take care of all that if you just bind to a model that matches the front-end model.

What exactly do you mean by "the id value appears in date format on the backend side"? Do you mean the FormData string has a JSON string inside with an id property which is represented as a string? And when you inspect the payload being sent from the browser, what does that look like?

Why not create an Id property in your FormDataWithFilesDto class? So that the deserializer knows what your property type is and deserializes correctly.

@StriplingWarrior, for example, it sends the id value as 4781, but when it comes to the backend, it appears as 1970-01-01T02:00:04.781. However, when this number is a number other than 4 digits, for example 82321, it appears normally this time. The id and type appear correct until I subscribe to the frontend.

@YongShun, this class is requested to be used in the project I am involved in, so I use it. But you are right, I will try what you said.

@Shadouspan: I understood that, as you explained it in your question. What you didn't explain is what you mean by "appears." Can you share an example of the JSON payload that the browser is sending (via Chrome dev tools, e.g.), and the value of the FormData property in your controller's SaveStudent method?

@StriplingWarrior, sorry for misunderstood. I added the model visible in the console and the payload in the Network tab under the title. I also added the service.ts part and the generic function used here. You can check now.
